# generate C/C++ variable names using preprocessor condition

Tags: c-preprocessor

I would like to conditionally generate a variable name depending on a compile time constant. There may be other ways of doing this but I would like to see if this is even feasible using the preprocessor.

```cpp
#define FUNC(X) ((X > 10) ? foo : bar)

#define CONCAT1(x,y) x##y

#define CONCAT(x,y) CONCAT1(x,y)

int main() {
  // Does not compile and generate "int x_bar;"
  int CONCAT(x_, FUNC(4));
}
```

Comment: Isn't it much easier to type `x_4` instead of `CONCAT(x_, FUNC(4))`?

Comment: There's a hint of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) around this. _Why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: 4 is used here as an example, that would be a preprocessor define in practice. FUNC(X) should return one of two alternatives based on its argument

Comment: What would be the point of changing the variable name? Why not use the same name and change how the variable is used?

Comment: There are preprocessor libraries like Boost.PP that can have built-up functionality, including this. They generally need to be built on a pretty awkward foundation that you don't want to have to do yourself.

Comment: So, describe your task, not a random code and "it doesn't work".

Comment: I'm learning about the preprocessor and in the process trying to understand if such a thing is feasible. Instead of variable name, the macro could return a type for example based on the input value

FUNC(X) x{};  // where FUNC(X) is one of two types based on some threshold on X

Comment: For what it's worth, the type use case is covered by `std::conditional`: `std::conditional_t<(X > 10), foo, bar>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that macros do direct token substitution.  So this:

```
CONCAT(x_, FUNC(4))
```

Would expand to this:

```
x_((4 > 10) ? foo : bar)
```

Which is not valid for token concatenation.  You should instead put the condition in an `#if` and define `FUNC` based on the result of that:

```
#define X 4

#if (X > 10)
#define FUNC foo
#else
#define FUNC bar
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you @dbush, this extends nicely to multiple thresholds.